# Add complex markup with event handlers

Tags: slickgrid

How to put into a grid cell not just a string `<span>text</span>`, but a string with an event handler?
This option does not suit me:

```
<span onclick='function(){...}'>click me</span>
```

I need to add, for example, such elements in one grid cell:

```
var $el1 = $('<button>clck me 1</button>').click(function(){...});
var $el2 = $('<button>clck me 2</button>').click(function(){...});
...
```

---

I use slick.dataview.

Comment: At first you need to create a Cell Formater that transform the value in a html element. In this element add a class attribute. Create a onRenderCompleted event, inside the function of event, you can add the selector handler like click. See the source code in [link]http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example2-formatters.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't.
Either handle click events via SlickGrid by using the onClick event it exposes or use event delegation on a higher level (container or document) to catch it.  Add an attribute to the buttons to distinguish them later and decide which handler to execute.

Comment: I agree. And be careful if you add a click event, you must think if you will need a editable cell in future. Editable cells active their functionailty with one or two clicks, depend of configuration